A way to fit circles on 3D data
What I am trying to do is to fit a circle across all cross-sections of 3D point cloud data that resembles a pipe.
The data resembles a cylindrical shape with disconnected parts in between, which can be ignored at this point. These data are composed of X, Y, and Z component.

At first I thought it would be better to take a cross section of the data, and find the best circle to fit on it, then apply it across the entire data to get many circles.
I first was able to obtain the curve-fitting after swapping X and Z axis to make the data explicit(thanks to jlandercy for answering my previous question(Describing the data points with arc-shaped graph). Then extracted a circle from the point where slope is 0. This is the idea coming from the fact that a circle should be able to fit where it is 90 degrees between a horizontal and a vertical lines, as depicted with the following picture: .
To explain it in more detail, what I did was finding the point along the curve of the cross-section data where the slope is 0 and finding another point where slope is the infinite. But as there is no point along the curve where the slope is infinite, I have assumed that a perfect circle could not fit along the entire curve, but the best-fitting one could be drawn on the point where slope is 0. So I found the coordinates of the point whose slope is 0 and compared it with the lowest point of the cross-section data. I used their coordinates to find the center of the circle, and I used the difference of X component between the point of slope 0 and the center to find the radius. As a result, I was able to draw a circle that seems to fit best with the curve on the cross section as displayed in yellow in the picture below.
I ignored Y components at that time, because I found that their variance and standard deviation were very low compared to those of the X and Z components, meaning that they don't really affect my analysis.

Now my plan is trying to apply it across the entire data so that I can create circles for every cross section. Somewhat like below.

The ultimate goal is to connect the centers of these circles on every cross section of the data, to obtain a non-straight line, which I believe wouldn't be too difficult once I am able to obtain the circles on all the cross sections.
I hope that what I am trying to achieve is clear. I just have no idea how to apply my cross-section method across the original data at this point. I was thinking about taking a for loop to apply it across the entire data but I couldn't quite imagine how to specify the loop for it. I was trying to get some help of Chat-GPT, but it didn't really help me.
I also have tried other methods of finding certerline of the point cloud such as combination of Delanay Triangulation and Voronoi Tessellation as suggested by another post Fit Curve-Spline to 3D Point Cloud. But I was not able to succeed.
If anyone can give me some hint or advice, I would appreciate it.
The original data is too large so I am linking on my OneDrive with a link: Original Data
Here is the piece of my code for how I approached with my idea of cross-section circle fitting.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the point cloud data
data = pd.read_csv('data/selected_2.csv')
points = data.to_numpy()
x = points[:, 0]
y = points[:, 1]
z = points[:, 2]

# Calculate polynomial
a = np.polyfit(z, x, 7)
f_poly = np.poly1d(a)

# Find new x and y data along the curve
z_new = np.linspace(z[0], z[-1], 50)
x_new = f_poly(z_new)
data_new = np.vstack((z_new, x_new)).T

# Define the derivative function
def FindingDerivatives(data_new):
    slopes = []
    for i in range(len(data_new) - 1):
        z1, x1 = data_new[i]
        z2, x2 = data_new[i + 1]
        slope = (x2 - x1) / (z2 - z1)
        slopes.append((z1, slope))
    return slopes

# Define the function to find perpendicular line slopes
def FindingPerpendicular(slopes):
    perpendicular = []
    for z1, slope in slopes:
        if slope != 0:
            inverse = -1 / slope # Perpendicular line is the inverse of the original slope
        else:
            inverse = float('inf')  # Perpendicular to a horizontal line is a vertical line
        perpendicular.append((z1, inverse))
    return perpendicular

# Find the maximum slope element
def FindMinMaxSlopeElement(slopes):
    target_slope_elements = []
    max_slope_elements = 0
    min_slope_elements = 0
    max_slope = max(slopes)[1]
    min_slope = min(slopes)[1]
    print(max_slope, min_slope)
    for i in range(len(slopes)):
        if slopes[i][1] == min_slope:
            max_slope_elements = slopes[i]
        if slopes[i][1] == max_slope:
            min_slope_elements = slopes[i]
    target_slope_elements.append(min_slope_elements)
    target_slope_elements.append(max_slope_elements)
    return target_slope_elements

# Find the corresponding coordinates to the maximum slope element
def FindCorrespondingCoordinates(target_slope_elements, data):
    min_coordinates = []
    max_coordinates = []
    target_coordinates = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[:, 0][i] == target_slope_elements[0][0]:
            min_coordinates.append(data[:, 0][i])
            min_coordinates.append(data[:, 1][i])
        if data[:, 0][i] == target_slope_elements[1][0]:
            max_coordinates.append(data[:, 0][i])
            max_coordinates.append(data[:, 1][i])
    print(min_coordinates)
    print(max_coordinates)
    target_coordinates.append(min_coordinates)
    target_coordinates.append(max_coordinates)
    return target_coordinates

# Find the circle based on the coordinate values corresponding to the maximum and minimum slopes
def FindCircle(target_coordinates):
    circle_info = []
    center_z = target_coordinates[0][1] 
    center_x = target_coordinates[1][0]
    center = [center_z, center_x]
    radius = target_coordinates[0][0] - target_coordinates[1][0]
    print(center, radius)
    circle_info.append(radius)
    circle_info.append(center)
    return circle_info

# Draw the circle
def CircleDraw(circle, test_data, z_new, x_new):
    radius = circle[0]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(test_data[:, 1], test_data[:, 0])
    ax.plot(z_new, x_new, 'y')
    cir = plt.Circle((circle[1][0], circle[1][1]), radius, color='r',fill=False)
    center_label = f"center: \n {round(circle[1][0], 2), round(circle[1][1], 2)}"
    plt.annotate(center_label, xy=(circle[1][0], circle[1][1]), ha='center') 
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
    ax.add_patch(cir)
    ax.set_xlabel('Z Data')  # X axis data label
    ax.set_ylabel('X Data')  # Y axis data label
    plt.show()


# Organize the test data (only taking 'X' and 'Z' coordinates of the original data)
test_data = points[:, [0, 2]]
# Find the slope of the original data
slopes = FindingDerivatives(test_data)
# Find perpendicular lines of the original data
perpendicular = FindingPerpendicular(slopes)
# Find minimum and maximum slope elements 
target_slope_elements = FindMinMaxSlopeElement(slopes) 
print("Target Slopes", target_slope_elements)
# Find the target coordinates
target_coordinates = FindCorrespondingCoordinates(target_slope_elements, test_data) 
print("Target Coordinates: ", target_coordinates)
# Find the circle information
circle = FindCircle(target_coordinates)
print("radius: %s center: %s" % (circle[0], circle[1]))
# Call the circle function
CircleDraw(circle, test_data, z_new, x_new)


# Here is the cross-section of the data
# ('Y' components are not really used as I decided that they don't really affect my analysis)
X,Y,Z
1702113.3399999738,2434223.5100000203,9080.16
1702132.699999988,2434227.2700000107,9079.86
1702172.7199999988,2434233.629999995,9106.22
1702153.0400000215,2434230.4699999997,9087.98
1702143.6899999976,2434227.5699999933,9083.15
1702167.079999983,2434224.6899999976,9100.11
1702159.8799999952,2434236.3600000143,9093.52
1702177.9900000098,2434225.169999987,9113.97
1702192.0399999917,2434220.0899999742,9155.37
1702186.7199999988,2434228.7599999905,9128.54
1702191.330000013,2434221.2299999893,9174.77
1702182.9099999962,2434234.8899999857,9120.3
1702182.580000013,2434217.7899999917,9121.94
1702192.1200000048,2434219.9599999785,9164.910000000002
1702189.5399999917,2434224.2199999997,9137.12
1702191.229999989,2434221.3899999857,9146.08
1702188.9300000072,2434225.100000024,9185.21
1702183.5,2434216.300000012,9198.22
1702175.5,2434229.150000006,9220.28
1702178.099999994,2434224.9799999893,9209.75
1702188.080000013,2434226.4600000083,9223.87
1702184.669999987,2434231.9600000083,9196.33
1702214.9900000098,2434218.3599999845,9220.34


Please comment if my question is not clear enough. I will update and revise the question as much as necessary.
Thanks a lot!

this isn't actually about circles. it's not even about cylinders. it's about recovering pipes from a 3D scan for BIM purposes, isn't it? that is certainly a research project, way too wide in scope for a simple question on SO. -- also not image processing, but geometry processing. point clouds are geometry.

you could iterate this. find a starting "disc". make sure it's aligned along the pipe, not angled. take a small step along the pipe. fit another disc, and so on, until some stopping condition.

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your advice. I was actually afraid that this might be a bigger problem than I have imagined, and was quite hesitant to post it here on SO, but I got stuck for too long that I wanted to get some help on it. I will definitely try your advice and let you know if I have more questions. Thanks for your comment!

You did not specify a programming language, so if C++ works for you, PCL could be what you are looking for. PCL has an implementation of the RANSAC method to find a geometric model in noisy data. Many different models are supported, most interesting for you would be CIRCLE2D, CIRLCE3D, and CYLINDER (see https://pointclouds.org/documentation/group__sample__consensus.html)
Here is a tutorial on how to fit a cylinder: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/cylinder_segmentation.html

Sorry about that I am using Python to do this. I couldn't search quite the same material with Python, do you happen to know one?

If there is no other way that I can think of doing this on Python, I am willing to move over to C++ to look for a way out. But I just want to able to make sure that I try everything on Python before I do so.

Sorry, no, I don't know an equally good way to do this in Python.

Ok I see well I will try some more with Python and if it doesn't work, then I may need to move on to C++ to see if it works. Thank you for your great tips!

there seem to be Python bindings to PCL

As stated in the comments on your original post, it seems that the problem you're trying to solve could be summarized as follow: extract the neutral axis of 3D scanned pipes. It is indeed a research project of its own.
One solution would be to fit 3D circles/cylinders to your points and then find a curve passing by their centers. For this to work, you must make sure that your original pointcloud has been perfectly segmented first (i.e., divided in different parts corresponding to pieces of circles/cylinders), as fitting algorithms (in the sense of least-squares) are very sensible to the presence of outliers. This segmentation step is doable manually but quite tedious. I'm not sure robust automated techniques exist.
RANSAC-based techniques are theoretically robust to the presence of outliers but quite computationally expensive and non-deterministic (i.e., do not produce the same output between different runs). You may try to write you own RANSAC implementation, but I'd advise you to try existing implementations (such as the one found in CloudCompare) first.
Another option would be to rely on the notion of principal curvatures, which would directly give you the radius of the circles along the principal directions of your cylindric surface (in your case radial and axial directions) for each point of your pointcloud. However, the computation of these principal curvatures is quite sensible to noise. I could not find Python code to compute the principal curvatures in the case of a pointcloud, but you may try using CloudCompare again to compute the Gaussian and Mean curvatures, and deduce the principal curvatures afterwards.
Hope that helps!
